# I need to Truncate process id for a process named chrome.exe in windows command line

Tags: windows, process

I need to Truncate process id for a process named chrome.exe in windows command line.

I tried
tasklist | FIND "chrome.exe"

It gives complete line whith process name, process id and all other thing, but I only want to Truncate the process id for this process "chrome.exe"

Comment: Do you mind using [tag:powershell]? `Get-Process chrome |ForEach-Object Id` will give you the list of PIDs of currently running chrome processes (`powershell -command Get-Process chrome ^|% id` from `cmd.exe`)

Comment: What does "truncate process ID" even mean?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by the question, but I think this will help you

```
open google | Press (Shift)and(ese)
```